# Can Oracle SQL*Loader work without a control file

Tags: database, oracle, sql-loader, controlfile

I am using SQL*Loader to push lot of CSV files to Oracle database. I am building intelligence using JAVA to create control file's content. Reason is That the nature of data is such that the control file's content changes with every CSV file i get. Or atleast i have to open the control file and perform few checks. I want to save the cost of creating, opening and other costs associated with the file I/O operation. I want to maintain the control file information in memory and and provide that data structure to SQL*Loader command instead of specifying the Control file.

Answer (score 0):

SQL*Loader is the wrong tool for the job.  It is designed for *repeatable* loads.  Clearly that's not what you're doing.

> "I want to save the cost of creating, opening and other costs associated with the file I/O operation."

And your benchmark for this onerous cost is ... ????

Anyway, if you really want to load from a different file structure each time you need something which can read the file header and generate a dynamic SQL statement for loading the rest of the file's content.

Personally I would choose top use PL/SQL for this, providing I could get the file on to the database server.  If I had to load it from the client then maybe a Java program would be the answer.  However, transferring the file's content across the network remains the real I/O cost.  Getting it delivered to the right server is the best saving on offer in this scenario.